# Send message to iframe from main page in localhost

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to send a message between two files that are in the same folder in localhost, main.php and iframe.php, but the iframe does not listen to it, I have tried to use many target origin like this:

mainpage.php

```
<body>
    <iframe src="iframe.php" class="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
<script>

    const iframe = document.querySelector('.iframe');
    
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("message sent from localhost/mainpage.php","http://localhost/iframe.php");

</script>
```

and inside the iframe.php to listen to the message i use

```
window.onmessage = function(event) {

    alert(event.data);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

Comment: disinfor Hi, you don't answer my question. I want to know if the origin target is misspelled or not. How should I write the origin target, so that the message reaches the iframe?

Comment: I don't need to send a function to the iframe, I want to send a message

Comment: It should definitely be `"[scheme]://[host]:[port]"` so I assume in your case `"http://localhost"` or `"http://localhost:12345"`

Comment: Pieterjan hello, I tried both alternatives without success (http://localhost:80 that is my server port)

Comment: It’s possible you’re attempting to send the message before the iframe has loaded, before the `onmessage` handler is registered.

Comment: ray Hello, I tried to use the <script> in the head without results, now it is seen that the <script> is below the <body>, I also used an `window.addEventListener("message",function(){})` in the iframe to hear the message without success. How do you send a message to the iframe on localhost with postMessage? thanks

Comment: Just to see if this is the problem wrap your postMessage call in a setTimeout to delay it for a few seconds.

Comment: ray Thanks you have answered my question, to use setTimeout in postMessage and it worked, put this comment as an answer to validate it and that others can see it

Comment: @woodfile Posted an answer with one of many possible ways to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you're invoking `postMessage` before your iframe content has loaded. There are numerous ways to solve this, one of which is to listen for a "load" event on the iframe before attempting it.

Would look something like this:

```js
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

iframe.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log('iframe loaded')
  
  // iframe has loaded; can post messages now.
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("message sent from localhost/mainpage.php","http://localhost/iframe.php");
});
```

```html
<iframe src="//example.com"></iframe>
```